# Template tags to display custom post type posts in category template?

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, theme-development, templates

I am developing a custom theme with custom post types involved. Custom post types have been defined via plugin 'Pods' (http://pods.io).

When writing a category.php, I realized, that the standard loop does not retrieve custom post types (CPT) posts which belong to a certain category. Is that right? If not, are there any template tags available to render CPT posts of a specific category?

Or is the right way to rather retrieve CPT posts via WP_Query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom post types are by default excluded from the main query except on taxonomy pages and custom post type archives.

You can simply use `pre_get_posts` to correctly alter the main query (*alter the query variables before the SQL query is build and executed*) to your needs.

Just a few notes on `pre_get_posts`

- `pre_get_posts` runs front end and back end queries, so it is very important to do the `is_admin()` check for queries only meant to run front end or back end
- `pre_get_posts` alters all custom instances of `WP_Query`, `get_posts()` (*which uses `WP_Query`*) and the main query (*which also uses `WP_Query`*). You would want to use the `is_main_query()` check to specifically only alter the main query.

You can do the following in a plugin or your theme's functions.php

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $q )
{
    if (    !is_admin() // Only target front end queries
          && $q->is_main_query() // Only target the main query
         && $q->is_category() // Only target category archives
    ) {
        $q->set( 'post_type', ['post', 'custom_post_type'] ); // Adjust as needed
    }
)};
```

Comment: That did the trick, fantastic! Thnx

Comment: Glad it worked. Enjoy ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `taxonomy.php` instead of category.php

Give little reading to template heirarchy on https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

All your custom posts will use `taxonomy.php` if you have some custom taxonomy defined.

For eg: lets suppose there are two taxonomies i.e `tax1 & tax2`

If you want the same template for both taxonomies then go with `taxonomy.php`

But if you want different templates for `tax1 & tax2` then use

`taxonomy-tax1.php`  &  `taxonomy-tax2.php` accordingly

I hope i was able to clear out few things for you .

All the best

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @terminator. I'm going to try taxonomy,php as you suggested. I haven't used it so far, because I haven't actually defined a custom category taxonomy but rather used the default 'category' taxonomy with my custom post type. Hence, I was assuming that any standard category.php (or other archive.php) template file would also fetch CPT posts by default...

Comment: actuallly standard archive.php would do the job but not the category.php

Comment: If I use standard archive.php, Wordpress routing does not consider which category has been called. Say, if user requests http://example.com/category/my-category archive.php does not know the category id to filter cpt posts from. I guess, I'll have to get into hooks to alter the default query behaviour of the category.php template...?